# Implementing floating inline labels (with EditText?)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Google's [Material Design text field guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels) present **floating labels** for text input:

> With floating inline labels, when the user engages with the text input
>   field, the labels move to float above the field.

[image]

Simple question: what's the best way to implement floating labels (on Android 5.0+)? Can you easily do it with standard components like `EditText`, and if so, how? Or is it simpler to go with a 3rd party lib?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can now use the official Android DESIGN Support Library (available from support library 22.2.0)

http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Add this dependency to start using the library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Wrap the EditText in a TextInputLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
```

you can customize TextInputLayout style

```
<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: am using android studio 1.3.2 for that when i add that compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' showing project errors even after sync also  mycompile sdkversion 23  build tools 23.0.1 and targetsdk version 23 please help me

Comment: In case anyone else needs to add the 'app' namespace, it's:  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Library [AndroidFloatLabel](https://github.com/IanGClifton/AndroidFloatLabel):

> For most use, you can simply use the custom view in your XML layout,
>   specifying a label to use as both the EditText hint and the label
>   TextView with the android:hint property. Example:
>
> ```
> <com.iangclifton.android.floatlabel.FloatLabel
>     android:id="@+id/float_label_1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:hint="@string/example_label" />
> ```
>
> You can also dynamically set the label with
>   `floatLabel.setLabel("Custom Label")` or
>   `floatLabel.setLabel(R.string.custom_label)`.
>
> Custom Layout
>
> If you want to specify a custom layout to use, you can do something
>   like this:
>
> ```
> <com.iangclifton.android.floatlabel.FloatLabel
>     android:id="@+id/float_label_custom_layout_1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:hint="@string/example_label"
>     android:layout="@layout/custom_float_label" />
> ```
>
> Your custom layout should include a label TextView (id/float_label)
>   and an EditText (id/edit_text). Right now, the custom layouts are
>   extremely limited because the FloatLabel simply lays out the label and
>   the EditText and ignores all other views. This is very efficient but
>   also prevents you from creating a much more complex layout. Here's an
>   example:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@id/float_label"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:lines="1"
>         android:textIsSelectable="true"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@id/edit_text"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:inputType="text|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textAutoComplete" />
> </merge>
> ```

Comment: **Please use quote formatting for copied text**, it is *dishonest* to present someone else's words as your own.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

in main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#4644aa">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="#3FFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:mtf_cardCollapsedHeight="4dp"
        app:mtf_image="@drawable/ic_mail_grey600_24dp"
        >

        <!--
        app:mtf_animationDuration="1000"
        app:mtf_cardColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:mtf_labelColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
        -->

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:textColorHint="#666"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in Main.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

//import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;

//import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }

}
```

and u also use this library.

https://github.com/florent37/MaterialTextField.